# E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) After upgrading

Tags: upgrade

after upgrading when i try to do sudo apt upgrade i got this message

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic
 linux-headers-generic
 linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04
 linux-generic-hwe-22.04
 linux-generic
 linux-image-6.2.0-20-generic
 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: What OS & release are you using?   Your provided packages appear to be from more than a single release if it's a Ubuntu system, why not tell us?  Also provide the full messages & not just the final summary (the error message is further up the listing/report)

Comment: `dkms status` please also `df -h;df -i` [edit] your question for output please.

Comment: You've shown us the error summary at the end, but not in earlier, individual error messages, which have more detail. Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Don't use Add Comment, or you'll classify yourself as "Does Not Follow Instructions (DNFI)", and I'll ignore you. I view DNFIs as unhelpable.